# Clear fields on browser's back button

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have disabled browser's back button using following Javascript code.
It works but I want a code which will clear all the fields on my form or atleast reload my page over browser's back button click. I am using c#.

Any help is appreciated. Thank You.

```
  function DisableBackButton() {
      window.history.forward()
  }
  DisableBackButton();
  window.onload = DisableBackButton;
  window.onpageshow = function (evt) { if (evt.persisted) DisableBackButton() }
  window.onunload = function () { void (0) }
```

---

---

I have tried doing this. But doesn't work

```
 Protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tbPs.Text = " ";
            tbName.Text = " ";
            tbEmail.Text = " ";
            tbContact.Text = " ";
            tbSug.Text = " ";
            rbTheme3.Checked = true;
            rbFoodVar3.Checked = true;
            rbTransport3.Checked = true;
            rbLoc3.Checked = true;
            rbTime3.Checked = true;
        }
```

Comment: what does your form contain? textboxes only? or selectboxes also?

Comment: @AmmarHasan textboxes and radiobuttons

Comment: textboxes can be easily cleared but for radio buttons, are there any default values?

Comment: yes lets say on every button group I want no. 3 radio button checked. @AmmarHasan

Comment: put your clearing code inside the unload function

Comment: @EuphoriaGrogi  You mean Page_Load function of the page?

Comment: @Prajakta_P i mean this function ` window.onunload = function () { void (0) }` everytime you navigate away from the page this function is called

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this in javascript inside `unload` function

For textboxes

```
$('input:text').val('');
```

For checkboxes

```
$('input:checkbox').prop('checked', false);
```

For radioboxes

```
var radioGroups = [];

$("input:radio").each(function(){
    if (radioGroups.indexOf(this.name) > -1) { return; }
    radioGroups.push(this.name);
});

radioGroups.forEach(function (groupName) {
   var $group = $('input[name="' + groupName + '"]:radio');
   $group.prop('checked', false);
   // if you want to select the third one
   $group[2] && $($group[2]).prop('checked', true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now);
```

The above code will disable page cache. Since the page is not being cached on the browser, the page will be reloaded when the user hits the back button.